# How to convert a list object to bigdecimal in prepared statement?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am using prepared statement for bulk insertion of records. Iam iterating a list which contains values and their dataTypes differ. One of the data type is BigDecimal and when i try to set calling preparedstatement, it is throwing null pointer exception.

My code

```
                int count = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {                     
                    if(list.get(j) instanceof Timestamp) {
                        ps.setTimestamp(count,  (Timestamp) list.get(j));       
                    } else if(list.get(j) instanceof java.lang.Character) {
                        ps.setString(count, String.valueOf(list.get(j)));
                    }
                    else if(list.get(j) instanceof java.math.BigDecimal) {
                        ps.setBigDecimal(count, (java.math.BigDecimal)list.get(j));
                    } else {
                        ps.setObject(count, list.get(j));   
                    }                           
                    count++;
                }
```

I tried 2 ways to convert, casting the object and tried to create a new object of type BigDecimal

```
ps.setBigDecimal(count, new BigDecimal(list.get(j).toString));
```

both donot solve my problem. It is throwing null pointer exception.

help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your stacktrace and the precise line that's throwing it ?

Comment: Why do you need the "instanceof java.math.BigDecimal" branch? Why not use ps.setObject(count, list.get(j)) if you already have BigDecimal in the list?

Comment: thanks for the replies, the problem was i was closing my preparedstatement and setting the preparedstatement to null inside try catch block inside the for loop. The issue is resolved. Thanks Brian and Dan for your valuable time.

Comment: Question does not make sense. How can a list of anything be a BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found, it seems to be useful for all kind of Object to primitive types.

```
public static BigDecimal getBigDecimal( Object value ) {
    BigDecimal ret = null;
    if( value != null ) {
        if( value instanceof BigDecimal ) {
            ret = (BigDecimal) value;
        } else if( value instanceof String ) {
            ret = new BigDecimal( (String) value );
        } else if( value instanceof BigInteger ) {
            ret = new BigDecimal( (BigInteger) value );
        } else if( value instanceof Number ) {
            ret = new BigDecimal( ((Number)value).doubleValue() );
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("Not possible to coerce ["+value+"] from class "+value.getClass()+" into a BigDecimal.");
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

here is the link: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ConvertObjecttoBigDecimal.htm